# Why does a push of a hash onto an array seem to be overwriting all of the array elements?

Tags: perl

Just wondering if I am doing something wrong or if this is a perl bug...I want to create an array of hash values.  I am using 'push' to put the values onto the array.  The first write of a hash to the array works fine, but when I push a second different hash onto the array, the first array element seems to get overwritten with what I just pushed onto the array.  Why is this happening?  See code below:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %val;

%val = (key1 => "Val1");

my @myArr;

my $cnt = push(@myArr,\%val);

print "After push (should contain 1 element): " . Dumper(@myArr) . "\n";

%val = (key2 => "Val2");

my $cnt = push(@myArr,\%val);

print "After push 2: (should contain 2 different elements):" . Dumper(@myArr) . "\n";
print " You can see above that element 1 and 2 of the array equal each other when they should be different\n";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"perl bug" - yeah, fat chance. :-)

You're pushing a reference to a hash into your array, then changing that very hash, and then you are pushing the same reference once again.

You probably need a copy or a whole different hash:

Different variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; # always use strict
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( %val, %other_val, @myArr );

%val       = ( key1 => "Val1" );
%other_val = ( key2 => "Val2" );

push(@myArr, \%val);
push(@myArr, \%other_val);

print Dumper(\@myArr) . "\n";
```

Copying:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; # always use strict
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( %val, %other_val, @myArr );

%val = ( key1 => "Val1" );
push(@myArr, { %val } );

%val = ( key2 => "Val2" );
push(@myArr, { %val } );


print Dumper(\@myArr) . "\n";
```

Comment: Just a sidenote. But your "copying" only works if the hash is simple key to string values. If the %val contains also arrayrefs or hashrefs you need a "deep copy". Best is to use a module like "Clone" for it. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone

Comment: So what? Shouldn't the array contain a bunch of references to the hash, instead of overwriting the same element over and over? Is push not just adding a scalar reference onto the array?

Comment: @felwithe yes, the original code pushes two references to the same hash into the array. Then the author is modifying the referenced hash and is wondering why it doesn't contain hash values before the hash was modified. Nothing is being overwritten in the array, it's the hash that's changing.

Answer (score 2):

Notice how you're pushing a *reference* to the hash %val? Well, if you modify that hash, the reference is naturally going to point at a different value.

Answer (score 0):

This is very natural: you use the same container `%val` twice. You explicitly override its contents.

Answer (score 0):

References in Perl behave a bit differently than many programmers are used from other programming languages. E.g. consider this Perl code:

```
my %person = ();
$person{"name"} = "John Doe";
$person{"age"} = 34;
```

and then you obtain a reference to it:

```
my $personRef = \%person;
```

In most programming languages that statement reads as "*Get the memory address of the backing storage used by `%person` and write it to `$personRef`*". In these languages I can then change `%person` itself (not the memory it points to) and this won't have any effect on `$personRef` still pointing to the same memory as before which still contains the same values as before.

But in Perl this statement rather reads as "*Let `$personRef` **always** point to the memory currently in use by `%person`*". The important keyword here is always, as that means if you make changes to `%person`, these changes are immediately reflected by the reference, too.

Thus when you do this in Perl:

```
my %person = ();
$person{"name"} = "John Doe";
$person{"age"} = 34;

my $personRef = \%person;

%person = (); # <-- Assigns new empty hash!
$person{"name"} = "Jane Doe";
$person{"age"} = 47;

print "$personRef->{'name'}\n";
```

It will in fact print "Jane Doe", as no matter what you do to `%person`, `$personRef` will always point to the memory in use by `%person`, even when you assign a new empty hash to `%person`, the reference will now point to that empty hash.

One could basically say: In Perl, references are not references to the memory used by values but to variables that reference these values. At any time you use the reference to access the value, the current value of the referenced variable is used for that and this may have changed plenty of times since the creation of the reference.

The accepted answer solves this issue by copying the hashes:

```
my @people = ();

my %person = ();
$person{"name"} = "John Doe";
$person{"age"} = 34;
push @people, { %person };

%person = ();
$person{"name"} = "Jane Doe";
$person{"age"} = 47;
push @people, { %person };
```

But wait, where are the hashes copied here? Well, it's Perl magic. To create a new hash, you can use that syntax:

```
my %hash = (
    "name" => "John Doe",
    "age" => 34
);
```

But that is just syntactical sugar, as in fact you can also use `,` instead of `=>`:

```
my %hash = ("name", "John Doe", "age", 34);
```

When converting a hash to a list, every first list item is a key and every second list item is its value, so when creating a hash from a list, the list values are interpreted exactly that way. Now if you want to directly create a reference to a hash, you can write:

```
my $hashRef = { "name", "John Doe", "age", 34 };
```

And this is basically the same as writing:

```
my $hashRef = { %myHash };
```

This reads as "*Create a new hash (`{}`), fill it with the values from `%myHash` and write a reference to it to `$hashRef`*". This is exactly what happens in this line:

```
push @people, { %person };
```

Except that the reference the newly created hash is directly pushed onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to **visualize** what happens:

Add this line after `use Data::Dumper;` :

```
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
```

Replace your prints by:

```
print 'After push 1 size of @myArr is ' . @myArr . " : @myArr \n" . Dumper(\@myArr);
```

and

```
print 'After push 2 size of @myArr is ' . @myArr . " : @myArr \n" . Dumper(\@myArr);
print 'Address of %val is: ' . \%val . "\n";
```

*Note the usage of `Dumper(\@myArr)`, not `Dumper(@myArr)` as it is the case in the question.*

You will get this output:

```
After push 1 size of @myArr is 1 : HASH(0xa0003bfb0)
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'key1' => 'Val1'
          }
        ];
After push 2 size of @myArr is 2 : HASH(0xa0003bfb0) HASH(0xa0003bfb0)
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'key2' => 'Val2'
          },
          {
            'key2' => 'Val2'
          }
        ];
Address of %val is: HASH(0xa0003bfc0)
```

Now it is obvious that $myArr[0] and $myArr[1] contain the same value, the address of %val: `0xa0003bfb0`.

So, %val, %{$myArr[0]} and %{$myArr[1]} are the same hash. Changing one affect the others.

*Note: `$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;` disables a visualization optimization when there is cross-referencing.
Make a test without this line and check the [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) documentation.*